# Uncaught type error jquery SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have this query working fine in SharePoint 2010. now i upgraded to 2013. The page which has following java script is throwing this error. everywhere else i don't see the error.

I am assuming if this script is causing error. 
Is anything wrong with the syntax of the script here. 
the function declarations.

```
<input type="button" value=">>" id="PuMoveIn" expression='lstPubs|lstPubsIn'    source="hdnlstPubs"  destination="lstPubsIn"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(":button[id$='MoveIn']").click(function () {
        var k = $(this).attr('expression');
        var s = $(this).attr('source');
        var d = $(this).attr('destination');
        if (k != null) {
            var p = k.split("|");
            $("select[id$='" + p[0] + "']" + " option:selected").remove().appendTo("select[id$='" + p[1] + "']");
            var v = $("select[id$='" + d + "']>option").map(function () { return this.value }).get().join(",");
            $("input[id$='" + s + "']").val('' + v + '');
        }
    });

});

function validateForm() {
    //codes here 

}
```

Comment: I suppose that error is not being thrown from those code lines but in one of the include files. Can you provide more code?

Comment: the code is ok. it works in SP 2010 3.5 framework but now in 2013 it is 4.5 .net framework. It is a listbox javscript where you move items with the >> and << buttons from one container to other container.

Comment: The error seems to be on jQuery declaration of sharepoint. I meant your code don't have any mention that trigger the sharepoint. Probably isn't your code.

Comment: i added few codes there is an input button which triggers the function to swap the element which is not working now

Comment: This code is working also. As I said, it can be on sharepoint declaration and this code depends only on jquery by the way. You can see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/84n3cvmy/)

Comment: yeah it seems like this page doesn't load j query at all. every other pages load the j query. i am not sure why this page doesn't load the j query. it is conflicting somewhere. just not able to find where is the conflict. J query link references are part of master pages and it works everywhere else except this page which complains about the j query function.